# How to bind button to control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am new to WPF. I have a button on my mainwindow

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSelect" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"   
      Content="Select" 
     IsEnabled="{Binding CanExec,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

and in myViewModel

```
    private bool _canExecute;
    private ICommand saveCommand;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
          CreateSaveCommand();

    }
   private void CreateSaveCommand()
    {
        this.saveCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(this.OnSaveClick,    this.CanSaveExecute);
    }
    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get { return this.saveCommand; }
    }
    private void OnSaveClick(object arg)
    {


    }
    private bool CanSaveExecute(object arg)
    {
        return CanExec;

    }

    public bool CanExec
    {

        get { return _canExecute; }
        set { _canExecute = value; OnPropertyChanged("CanExec"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
```

But the button always remain disabled..What am I missing ??

Comment: nothing is setting CanExec to true? so your button is always disabled?

Comment: Note: by default value of Boolean in C# is false.

Comment: Please show your implementation of `OnPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Where is your `SaveCommand` defined? Also if you use a RelayCommand with `OnExecuted/ CanExecuteExecuted` it's not necessary to do `IsEnabled` in XAML

Comment: @Sheridan please take a look

Comment: Can you show the implementation of SaveCommand?

Comment: I would also highly recommend using a MVVM Framework like MVVM Light (https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) which for example already has many functions build in a ViewModel base class plus extended command handling

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your implementation of the `OnPropertyChanged` method... at present, the event will only get called *if it is `null`*, which of course, would cause an `Exception`. Try this instead:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string p)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Your `Binding Path` is also incorrect, but that would not stop it from working... it should be like this:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSelect" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"   
    Content="Select" />
```

Please note that `ICommand.CanExecute` does *not* have to be set to the `IsEnabled` property manually... the Framework will do that for us.

Comment: It doesnt work at my side I am setting the value of CanExec to true in other part of my code which I am able to see using debugger..Is the binding correct ?

Comment: Are you messing around? Now `CanExec` is always `false`... what are you doing? Just `return true` from `CanSaveExecute` for now.

Comment: If I do private void `myListobx_selectionchanged(object sender, selectionEventArgs e){CanExec=true;if (SaveCommand.CanExecute(null))SaveCommand.Execute(null);}` Now I am able to set the value of CanExec as `true`

Answer (score -1):

Default value for Bool is 'False', so your CanExec return 'False' and your button disabled.